# Can I define android:icon in code?

Tags: android

I had to build separate bundle for two different android phones, and the two have different icon. I do not want to modify the manifest file everytime when I build the application.

Can I define the icon in my code ?  as I can get the phone model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the icon programmatically, as it will be a part of your signed APK.

What kind of differences do you have between the 2 versions? And what is your current manual build process? If it's a manifest change, you could probably change your build scripts to produce 2 APKs using different data every time you build.